# How to Use Cell Text From Cell Being Checked by COUNTIF in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I'm wanting to do is have a formula in one cell that counts the values in a range that conform to a lookup of that range cell's value compared to another cell.

OMG, now that I look at it, that is totally confusing.  Let me try to clarify a lot here.

Say we have Cell1, which will hold the counting formula.  I have a list of values in a two-column table, Table1.  The range, Range1 that Cell1 will be counting from is a range of cells that have List Validation in them.  Table1 holds references to all values that can result from those Lists, in column 1.  I have another cell, Cell2, which holds a number value.  Column 2 of Table1 holds values that reference Cell2.  I need to count the number of values from Range1 whose row matches in Table1[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8yPP.png) match the value in Cell2.  Is there a way I can do this with COUNTIF without referencing each cell individually?  Is there some shorthand (like Range.currentValue) that I can use to get the value of the cell currently being checked?  The range is 11 rows long, and I need to do a second range that has 12 rows counted.

Man, I really don't know how to clarify that any more... I'll post this for now, in case anyone can understand what I'm saying and knows the answer, while I work on a sample spreadsheet I can upload.

I did my best to visually represent what I'm trying to accomplish:
http://gyazo.com/b83295baf3b156683a5c39b40c806504
[image]

Extended explanation: http://gyazo.com/4048802050e3dcfca7aee238acc2f7dd

[image]

Comment: Changed the references, I'm working on the example right now.

Comment: Alright, here's the picture demonstrating what I want:
http://gyazo.com/b83295baf3b156683a5c39b40c806504

Comment: http://gyazo.com/39609c98bc4e243920f0a96b05f81a3f  If that's not good enough, with all of my other explanations, then I give up.  Really didn't think I was making it hard, I thought that first one would actually help, as the exact values really shouldn't matter.

Comment: Urgh, scratch that, use this one instead: http://gyazo.com/4048802050e3dcfca7aee238acc2f7dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper column, say, between the brown and the first blue or at the right of the setup. Use a vlookup like

=vlookup(brownvalue,BluetableRange,2,false)

Then do a countif on the helper column

=countif(HelperColumn,"<="&GreenCellAddress)

[image]

You can hide the column with the helper if it upsets your spreadsheet design.

Comment: I guess I've been looking at the complicated side of this for too long.  I wish I could use the single formula answer that maybeWeCouldStealAVar gave, but alas, my design doesn't allow it.  And so, I'll be utilizing hidden columns for this spreadsheet.  Such a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and probably should) use a helper column as Teylyn suggests.  But, for when that may be inconvenient, you can also use an array formula:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(listlookupcolumn,rangeoflists,numbervaluecolumn,"<="&numbertomatch))`

To enter it as an array formula, type "ctrl-shift-enter" after editing the formula, rather than just "enter"

Rough explanation: since rangeoflists is in a place where a single value is expected, the `countifs` is calculated once for each value, and the array of results is passed to sum.  Use the "evaluate formula" feature to see the intermediate result array.

Afterthought: It occurs to me now that this does rely on listlookupcolumn containing unique values.  (Almost certainly true in this example.)  You can modify the formula a bit to get around this:

`=SUM(SIGN(COUNTIFS(listlookupcolumn,rangeoflists,numbervaluecolumn,"<="&numbertomatch)))`

The SIGN function will keep you from double counting.

Again, you must use "ctrl-shift-enter" for this to work. (Yes, as I'm sure others are ready to point out, you can also use the sumproduct hack in this instance.)

Comment: Ah, I see.  Very interesting.  Unfortunately for me, the count formula is going into a merged cell set, and Excel doesn't allow array formulas like that, but I'll definitely keep that on hand for later.

Comment: Two workarounds for that (other than unmerging): (1) use the `sumproduct` hack, replacing `sum` in the formula with it and don't enter as an array formula -- this will treat the single parameter you pass it as an array for the same effect. Or (2) use the formula to define a name using the name manager, and refer to the name in the merged cell -- named formulas are evaluated as arrays.